# CommandLine Runner Failed to load

Tags: spring, spring-boot, runtime-error

Facing exception  null pointer exception the class indicated in error mentioned here
it is saying user is null in override method. Cannot figure out the solution suggest some solution

I have given Error messages and as well every mentioned line for exception in the error message first one is main and second one is override method of addRoleToUser.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class UserserviceApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(UserserviceApplication.class, args);
}

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner run(UserService userService){
    return args -> {
    userService.saveRole(new Role(null,"ROLE_USER"));
    userService.saveRole(new Role(null,"ROLE_MANAGER"));
    userService.saveRole(new Role(null,"ROLE_ADMIN"));
    userService.saveRole(new Role(null,"ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"));
    userService.saveRole(new Role(null,"ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN_CE"));

    userService.saveUser(new AppUser(null,"Ahmad Mujtaba","ahmad","0000",new ArrayList<>()));
    userService.saveUser(new AppUser(null,"Hamid Mustafa","hamid","1234",new ArrayList<>()));
    userService.saveUser(new AppUser(null,"Areeb Dera","areeb","5678",new ArrayList<>()));
    userService.saveUser(new AppUser(null,"Fasih Ahmad","fasih","0000",new ArrayList<>()));
    userService.saveUser(new AppUser(null,"Shaheer Zafar","shaheer","1122",new ArrayList<>()));

        userService.addRoleToUser("ahmad","ROLE_USER");
        userService.addRoleToUser("hamid","ROLE_MANAGER");
        userService.addRoleToUser("areeb","ROLE_ADMIN");
        userService.addRoleToUser("fasih","ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN");
        userService.addRoleToUser("shaheer","ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN_CE");
    };


}

@Bean
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

}

Override method:

```
@Override
public void addRoleToUser(String userName, String roleName) {
    log.info("Adding role {} to user {}",roleName,userName);
    AppUser user= userRepo.findByUsername(userName);
    Role role=roleRepo.findByName(roleName);
    user.getRoles().add(role);
}
```

Exception Messsage:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
a org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:774)~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:755) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at io.getarrays.userservice.UserserviceApplication.main(UserserviceApplication.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.getarrays.userservice.models.AppUser.getRoles()" because "user" is null
at io.getarrays.userservice.service.UserServiceImpl.addRoleToUser(UserServiceImpl.java:65) ~[classes/:na]
at io.getarrays.userservice.service.UserServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cf86a147.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
      at io.getarrays.userservice.service.UserServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$51d7b74f.addRoleToUser(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
     at io.getarrays.userservice.UserserviceApplication.lambda$run$0(UserserviceApplication.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
... 8 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please add the **full stacktrace**.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.getarrays.userservice.models.AppUser.getRoles()" because "user" is null` – which means `user.getRoles()` throws that exception which means `user` is null which means `userRepo.findByUsername(userName)` returned null.